# Block Element does not take the full width of the page

Tags: html

I asked this question before but I'll try to explain in again as I can I
created a simple HTML Page,
when the elements increased more than 40 elements, the block elements does not take the same page width (for example if the page width 1090px, the element width 1073px) although I reset  the margin in CSS
the only code in CSS file is

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
```

and when the elements less than 40 elements, the block elements take the full page width

this is the HTML Code

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/test.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>test</div>
    <p>this is paragraph</p>

    <div class="lesson_5">
      <h2>Product Title</h2>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <h2>Product Title</h2>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <h2>Product Title</h2>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <h2>Product Title</h2>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <h2>Product Title</h2>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <h2>Product Title</h2>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <h2>Product Title</h2>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <h2>Product Title</h2>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
      <p>this is paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>





i tried to create simple HTML page and I expect that the block elements take the same page width
```

Comment: did a scroll bar get added so the width was reduced?

Comment: @Abdooo
I tried with 60 elements. But the block elements still taking full width. What's the issue here?
https://codepen.io/jahedul29/pen/gOqzqvd

Comment: Your example refers to a 17px difference, which is a common width of the browser scrollbar. You still have full width block elements.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Comment: @t-jam
many thanks for all who replay to my question 
you are right, now I noticed that when I added more than 40 elements the scroll bar appear and the width reduced, and when I delete one element the, the scroll bar hide and the element take full width, but now, how can I let the element  take the full width when the scroll bar appear (without deducting 17px of the scroll bar

Comment: @Pete Yes you are right, when the scroll bar appear, the width reduced.
now, is there any way to let the element take the full width although the scroll bar appear?

Comment: You could use a width of 100vw - but that means the when you get a vertical scrollbar, you will also get a horizontal one for the extra width taken by the scrollbar.  Why are you bothered about that little bit anyway?  You've not really explained why it's breaking your layout